# How to get pdf from decoded base64 string

Tags: php, base64, encode

how can i download pdf from this array, this is how my current code looks like, i cant get pdf to save. Thanks for your help.
this is my current code:

```
$result = $SoapClient4->getContractBill($contractId, 2019, '09');
    var_dump($result);
    #$base64data = preg_replace('#data:application/pdf/[^;]+;base64,#', '', $result['ContractBills'][0]['RawFileData']);
    $decoded = base64_decode($base64);
    $file = 'invoice.pdf';
    $file_put_contents($file, $decoded);

    $pdf_decoded = base64_decode($base64data);
    $pdf = fopen('test.pdf','w');
    fwrite($pdf,$pdf_decoded);
    fclose($pdf);
```

Comment: You need to use use the `rawFileData` and remove the `base64,` at the beginning.

Comment: @MarkusZeller is there an example of how i should do this?

Comment: If my answer works for you, please mark as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

- remove the 'base64,' (7 chars)
- decode the string
- write into file

```
file_put_contents('test.pdf', base64_decode(substr($result['ContractBills'][0]->rawFileData, 7)));
```

> Be aware of having proper upper/lower case of the keys, because they are case sensitive. `'RawFileData' !== 'rawFileData'`.

**EDIT** after your comment question:

You may replace your code with

```
$result = $SoapClient4->getContractBill($contractId, 2019, '09');
file_put_contents('invoice.pdf', base64_decode(substr($result['ContractBills'][0]->rawFileData, 7)));
```

That is all. Make sure, you are writing the invoice.pdf in the correct path.

The one-liner does the same as:

```
$result = $SoapClient4->getContractBill($contractId, 2019, '09');
$file = 'invoice.pdf';
$base64raw = $result['ContractBills'][0]->rawFileData;
$base64 = substr($base64raw, 7);
$decoded = base64_decode($base64);
file_put_contents($file, $decoded);
```

so you can decide which way you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Markus, I'm a little confused, how do I put that on my code?

Comment: I inserted all the last bit of code, and I got this error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Comment: Ah, yes, $result['ContractBills'] holds an array with object. I'll update the answer.